# How to create a secure API using R?

Tags: r, slack, plumber

I am trying to create an interactive app in Slack ([something like this](https://api.slack.com/interactive-messages)), which requires an interactive-endpoint to be created from my end.

The documentation provided by plumber is [here](https://www.rplumber.io/docs/security.html).

They say "**Unfortunately, Plumber does not implement HTTPS support natively, but most of the documented hosting options offer ways to deploy HTTPS and HSTS in front of your Plumber API**"

My question is, is there any other framework in R that allows me to create an endpoint securely? If not, is there any other better way of integration with Slack for interactive messages. Below I have demonstrated what I am looking for.

Database -> R (Rscript pulls data and reformats) -> Slack (Question posted in a slack channel from R) -> Response from Slack (once a user enters a choice) -> send it back to R where I can save the data/response

Forgive my lack of knowledge in the world of APIs/engineering, I'm a data scientist trying new things out.

FYI: I do have a windows server setup already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm extremely late to this, but one way to use HTTPs with plumber is to make a separate program convert HTTPS traffic to HTTP and back.

We did this as part of the Enterprise TensorFlow R Docker container we made for T-Mobile. Our solution uses Apache 2 to route the traffic to Plumber. Here is the GitHub repo which links to blog posts going into more detail about it. While Docker makes this easy to run, you don't need Docker for the Apache 2 part to solve your problem.

https://github.com/tmobile/r-tensorflow-api

Hope that helps!